# ActionRecord dates not using `default_timezone = :local` in ActionMailer messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

When sending emails using ActionMailer, the records' datetime appearing are show as UTC dates, not the local time stored and seen on records' from ActiveRecord. On views and rails console, dates are show correctly. Is there something specific from ActionMailer?